# cannot use env variable in groovy script outside of jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Team,
`${env.test_USR}` unable to use it outside of pipeline

I am able to set and use the variable inside pipeline but the same var is not working when sending slackNotify. for slack message am getting null that means env var was not found or read. any hint how to define env var outside pipeline so that slack can use it?

it works for `gerritCheck` and i get the id but var is not getting set for slackNotify call.

error output

```
https://sonar.company.com/dashboard?id=null
`
```

expected

```
https://sonar.company.com/dashboard?id=test_12345
```

```
notifyChannel = "#sw-test"

sonarStageLink = "SonarQube: <https://sonar.company.com/dashboard?id=${env.test_USR}>"


def slackNotify(String status, String color) {
    slackSend (
        channel: notifyChannel,
        color: color,
        message: "Analysis: \n${sonarStageLink}\n"
    )
}


pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'test'
    }

    environment {
        RUN_SONAR_URL = 'https://sonar.company.com'
        test = credentials('test-pullbranchanalysis')
    post {
        success {
            gerritCheck checks: ['jenkins:code-analysis': 'SUCCESSFUL'], url: "id=${env.test_USR}"
            script {
                if (!params.Refresh) {
                    echo "success"
                    slackNotify("succeeded", "good")
```

Comment: Where is `env.test_USR` assigned a value?

Comment: _USR is how that variable works when we use `credentials()`. groovy creates two vars _PSW and exposes them in container env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely an issue with the positioning of the variable. If you were to move the `sonarStageLink` variable in to the pipeline as an env variable, this should start working:

```
def slackNotify() {
    echo sonarStageLink
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        test_USR = "TEST"
        sonarStageLink = "SonarQube: <https://sonar.company.com/dashboard?id=${env.test_USR}>"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            script {
                slackNotify()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

> SonarQube: https://sonar.company.com/dashboard?id=TEST

Comment: awesome. worked like charm. btw: so there is no way I was doing it?